# I am crashing after selecting "try or install ubuntu"

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi

All,

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my PC alongside Windows. The process is as follows:

1. Download Ubuntu 22.04.1 from ubuntu releases
2. Flash download to USB with RUFUS
3. Restart the PC and enter bios through F2
4. Ensure CSM is disabled, Fast boot is disabled, and secure boot is disabled
5. Boot through UEFI USB device (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KF2R.jpg)
6. Select "Try or Install Ubuntu"
7. This screen appears (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7puha.jpg)
8. I click my arrow key to move to the screen where code is executing in the background and my computer freezes at this screen and resets (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tglQF.jpg)

I am new here, so if it is not clear I am not extremely savvy with computers, or at least not at this level. I want to be as helpful as possible and have listed my steps above. If there is ANYTHING I can provide to assist you please let me know in a detailed comment so I can collect the necessary information and provide it to you. These are all of my steps from download to crash.

Update: I've since updated my process and also included the below image of some of the startup code that appears after I do step 6.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWLXl.jpg

Update 2: I have since tried the following on separate occasions:

1. Replacing "quiet splash" with "nouveau.modeset=0"
2. nomodeset between "quiet splash" ('''quiet nomodeset splash''')
3. Deleting "quiet splash" and replacing it with "nouveau.noaccel=1"
4. Deleting "quiet splash" and replacing it with "noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll"

These have all yielding failures that freeze on the splash screen code. To be clear the splash screen code is proceeded fine with "OK" at each step and just eventually freezes around the same few lines of code each time. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz3Fh.jpg)

I am not receiving any relevant error codes from Ubuntu around the freeze.

Update 3

I have changed the boot to allow Other OS and it managed, only 1 time, to get me to the Ubuntu desktop. However, the desktop crashed a minute or so after loading without ever producing the install options.

I really have almost no idea of where to go from here as I have tried booting to Ubuntu over 150 times and its only ever reached the desktop 2 times. Please if anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated.

---

Additional information:
MB is Asus Prime X570-P
I have an Nvidia GPU

Thank you I will update as comments come in.

Comment: 1. Your No4 is wrong. CSM=Legacy mode support, you don't want that. Not a problem if you boot the installer in UEFI mode but better to ensure **CSM is disabled**. Fast Boot is optional but is generally recommended to be disabled to assure better hardware detection. 2. **What you should disable is Secure Boot** because you need Nvidia drivers. If dual-booting with Windows 11 you must manually sign the drivers and then re-enable SB. 3. Use the "safe graphics" option and don't forget to tick the option to install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc. to have the Nvidia drivers automatically installed.

Comment: I have implemented all of your changes and the system crashes at the load screen presented in step 7. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the vendor for any motherboard firmware updates, and hashchecked the downloaded ISO used to make the install media (and checked the media if offered).  Ever do a memory check? Note Fast Boot is a  machine setting to give you time to interrupt the boot sequence, it's not important to turn off, and makes things difficult.  Fast Startup is the Windows power option (buried in advanced/hidden links) which needs to be disabled to allow a normal boot to occur.